# Processing JSON data with D3

Tags: python, d3.js

I'm trying to create a bar graph of some data I have in a flask/python application. I've been looking at [this](https://github.com/dfm/flask-d3-hello-world) so far and am having issue getting d3 to actually import the JSON.

In the script I have a simple function that looks like this:

```
d3.json("/data", function(error, data){
    alert(data);
}
```

But this alert is never called nor is an error thrown. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
I'm using d3.min.js if it's relevant.

Comment: If you go to `/data` that your Flask instance is serving, do you get any data?

Comment: Yes, the data shows up as expected there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the order of javascript imports in my app. While I imported d3.js, I didn't import jQuery until after it. I moved around the script and imports, then it worked.